# What buttons do you press to use your UAV?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

I recently unlocked the UAV in the PS3 version of *Call of Duty: Black Ops 2*, and it says I've gotten enough of a killstreak to be able to use it, but I don't know how to actually use it! How do I use a UAV if and when I get one?

Answer (score 4):

### Controlling Scorestreaks (and other d-pad commands)

- <kbd>▲</kbd> or <kbd>▼</kbd> (Up or Down) : Cycles through available scorestreak rewards
- <kbd>►</kbd> (Right) : Use selected scorestreak reward
- <kbd>◄</kbd> (Left) : Arms underbarrel attachments

Comment: I thought the up/down arrows were for cycling through kill-streaks (on ps3).  Its been awhile though.

Answer (score 0):

ON PS3...

`►` (right) : uses the currently highlighted killsteak reward.

---

If you currently have more than one unused killstreak reward...

`▲` move up the list of killstreak rewards.

`▼` move down the list of killstreak rewards.